# Modify Dynamic Json structure to flat keys and value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, extjs

I want to change different json structure into flat structure for easily presentation on html. So I have n nesting inside data, sometimes I got key and value sometimes just value. Is there any easy way to do it ?

This is some example of json that I have:

```
         {
            "title": "example glossary",
            "GlossDiv": {
                "title": "S",
                "GlossList": {
                    "GlossEntry": {
                        "ID": "SGML",
                        "SortAs": "SGML",
                        "GlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
                        "Acronym": "SGML",
                        "Abbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
                        "GlossDef": {
                            "para": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
                            "GlossSeeAlso": ["GML", "XML"]
                        },
                        "GlossSee": "markup"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is something what I would like to get

```
        "glossary": {
            "title": "example glossary",
            "GlossDivTitle": "S",
            "GlossDivGlossListGlossEntryID": "SGML",
            "GlossDivGlossListGlossEntrySortAs": "SGML",
            "GlossDivGlossListGlossEntryGlossTerm": "Standard Generalized Markup Language",
            "GlossDivGlossListGlossEntryAcronym": "SGML",
            "GlossDivGlossListGlossEntryAbbrev": "ISO 8879:1986",
            "GlossDivGlossListGlossEntryGlossDefPara": "A meta-markup language, used to create markup languages such as DocBook.",
            "GlossDivGlossListGlossEntryGlossDefGlossSeeAlso": "GML, XML",
            "GlossDivGlossListGlossEntryGlossSee": "markup",
        }
```

I'm using sencha js and Idea is to present any kind of json inside html, something like this.

```
        tpl: new Ext.XTemplate(
            '<table border="1" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">',
            '<tpl foreach=".">',
            '<tr>',
            '<td>{$}</td>',
            '<td>{.}</td>',
            '</tr>',
            '</tpl>',
            '</table>'
            , {
                complied: true
            }
        )
```

Comment: This is a perfect example for a one-to-one model ;) Nothing you have to do then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recursion is a solution:

**UPDATED:**

```
const flattenedKeys = (json) => {

  // Container for the keys
  const flattenedObj = {};

  const traverse = (obj, currentPath = '') => {

    // Traverse all the properties
    Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {

      const newPath = currentPath + key;

      // If obj[key] is an array
      if (Array.isArray(value)) {

        value.forEach(item => {
          traverse(item, newPath)
        });

        return;
      }


      // If obj[key] traverse recursively nested properties
      if (typeof value === 'object') return traverse(value, newPath);

      // If obj[key] is not an object or an array
      flattenedObj[newPath] = value;

    });

  }

  // Traverse recursively the whole object
  traverse(json);

  return flattenedObj;

}
```

Comment: I think that this covers most of my structure, but still if I have something like this is not coverred. "functionalName": [{
                    "text": "Test",
                    "language": "eng"
                }],

Comment: This should be in use `Array.isArray(obj[item])` to check if the value is array.

Comment: True, i have just edited to include your case as well (when array can have items that are objects)

Comment: I still need some corrections. For example this "countryOfOrigin": ["191"] will result as countryOfOrigin0 - 1, countryOfOrigin1 - 9, countryOfOrigin2 - 1

Comment: Do you have a scenario where you have an array in array, like ([[[]]])?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not trying to do this for one specific json, idea is to cover any type of json to flat for presentation purpose.

Comment: How this should look like fhen flattened:

const obj = {a: [["str"], [[{b: "something"}], {c: "smg"}]]}

Comment: I hope that I will never get something like this :). But if I get "targetMarket": [ "191", "192"] that should look like "targetMarket": "191, 192". Also I notice if I have something like this "materials": [{"code": "CORRUGATED_BOARD_OTHER","compositionQuantity": [{"value": 360.00000,"unit": "GRM"}]},{"code": "POLYMER_PP","compositionQuantity": [{"value": 48.00000,"unit": "GRM"}]}] that I will get just one record from this.

Comment: Its kinda messy because you have requirements that are not unified. For example. If you have ["sad", "asdas"] you expect "sad, asdas", but what if you have ["sad", {a: 2}] what is your expected output? Or what is your expected output for array of objects? Lets say c: [{a:2}, {b:3}, c: {4}]? are keys then {c0a:2, c1b:3, c2c:4} or what? Its hard to tell if all the items of an array are of the same type? And there are a lot of different combinations?

Comment: Can you just try to cover two options from previous comment? I think that this will cover more then 90% my structure.

Comment: What is the expected output for : [{"code": "CORRUGATED_BOARD_OTHER","compositionQuantity": [{"value": 360.00000,"unit": "GRM"}]},{"code": "POLYMER_PP","compositionQuantity": [{"value": 48.00000,"unit": "GRM"}]}]

Comment: Like this "materialsCode": "CORRUGATED_BOARD_OTHER","materialsCodeCompositionQuantityValue": "360.00000, "materialsCodeCompositionQuantityValueUnit": "GRM", materialsCode1": "POLYMER_PP","materialsCodeCompositionQuantityValue1": "48.00000", "materialsCodeCompositionQuantityValueUnit": "GRM"

Comment: If its a case,  its really a mess to do all these manipulation, its easier to make a better structure in json before processing flattening. In your case materialsCodeCompositionQuantityValue1 index 1 is at the end of a string. And really in json its should be materialsCode1CompositionQuantityValue and so on... Its really hard to track and propagate all these things, and with this kind of a logic you can have a milion different combinations..

Answer (score 0):

If you want to flatten the object you will need to do recursive loop

Below is the simple sample just to give the idea on how it works, it doe not use recursive.

```js
// You data to be flatten
var obj = { ... }
var data = {}
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function (item) {
  // Check for value type of object
  if(typeof obj[item] == 'object') {
    // Check if array
    if(Array.isArray(obj[item])) {
      // Append the value
      data[item] = obj[item];
    } else {
      // Must loop to this object
      // You can recursive function
      var nestObj = obj[item];
      Object.keys(nestObj).forEach(nest => {
        // Append to the data
        // This time with nested object,
        // We have to merge the parents key and the nested key
        data[item+nest] = nestObj[nest]
      })
    }
  } else {
    // Append non object values
    data[item] = obj[item];
  }
})
```

Comment: I try but this is not result which I need, still is not flatten